# Sports – singular or plural

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, american-english, british-english

I am being told that "sports" is a singular noun. This is creating a problem for me (as a teacher) because it sounds 'odd' even if it is correct (i.e. one of the exceptions to the rule).

e.g. *Sports has* (rather than *sports have*)...

I always thought sports referred to more than one team activity (e.g. football, rugby, golf, bowls etc.); hence, it was plural.

For example,

> - *I like playing sports.*
> - *Sports have always been of interest to me.*

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is *sports* a collective noun?
2. Which usage is correct?

Comment: "Sports" is generally treated as a plural noun.  The confusion may be that in the US we use "sports" in many cases where UK people would say "sport".

Comment: Agreed.  The answer to this questions seems to be tied to regional differences in usage.

Comment: Is there an acceptable standard?

Comment: @JaveerBaker There are several. But most basically, _sports_ can both be a mass/uncountable noun (referring to the notion of [playing] sport[s] generally) and a plural, countable noun (referring to several distinct types of sport as being distinct). When it’s used as a non-count noun, it takes a singular verb; then it’s used as a count noun, it takes a plural verb. Compare with _physics_ and _math(s)_, which are also usually non-count nouns, unless you’re talking about distinct types of mathematics (which I suppose is at least theoretically possible).

Comment: Related: *[“Sport” vs “Sports” Origin](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212851)*

Comment: Important data on American usage [is available here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fraSdN-PG8).

Comment: I like to play sports. One sport I like playing is rugby.  So does John. A sport I don't like is tennis. However, I'll pass on the sport of name calling (in most instances.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "sports" is a singular noun. This is creating a problem for me (as a
> teacher) because it sounds 'odd' even if it is correct (i.e. one of
> the exceptions to the rule).

I am a teacher, too, and I remember that when I was a student, I was baffled by what seemed a more '*odd'* use and that is of *sports* as an adjective: "*sports* car"

But you can overcome your difficulty if you think of many words (like *economics* = economic activity/-ies) that are plural in appearance and nevertheless are treated as singular.

The only (slight) difference is that *sports* can be treated both as singular and plural: the plural usage is obvious, to justify the singular usage think that (like economics) it really means: **sporting activity/ies**

You can find a clear definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sport):

## sport:

- 1. a *contest* or ***game*** in which people do certain physical activities according to a specific set of rules and compete against each other

"Ice-skating with friends is my favorite **sport**."

- 2. **sports** in general
- 3. a **physical activity** (such as hunting, fishing, running, swimming, etc.) that is done for enjoyment

So, you use the singular for one type of 'sport' and the plural for 2 or more;

*"Football, basketball, and hockey are all team **sports**, 'I enjoy winter **sports** like skiing and skating.'"*

but you can use *indifferently* the singular **or** the plural form to indicate the 'physical activity':

"*I used to do a lot of sport when I was younger."*
You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport) that both forms are used for the same sentence:

> **Sport** (or **sports**) is all forms of usually competitive physical
> activity which, through casual or organised participation, *aim to
> use, maintain or improve physical ability and skills.*

You can find more examples on the web:

> ...“sports” as singular when it refers to a general field of activity or
> interest. He would say “*sports is my chief interest*, next to grammar,”
> because he is not thinking of different individual sports but about
> the field of athletics in general. Fry was referring to sports in
> general as a field of coverage, and, as Buck sees it, was right to use
> the singular.
>
> But when sports refers to a **number of individual** activities, it
> becomes plural. So Buck would say, “*my favorite sports are baseball,
> football and bronc-riding.”*

In conclusion, it is no exception to any rule, if 'sports is' sounds weird to you you can use the singular form in most contexts.

*Note* 1.: writing this post I realize that 'sports' used as an adjective can refer to **both** forms of the word: *sports* car, and *sports* column.

*Note* 2.: besides being an adjective, on its own *sports* is a singular noun when it is an elliptical form of:

- [a] sports [car]
- [the] sports [column]

Source: Oxford Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

When used to refer to different activities, "sports" is plural, but it is singular when used to refer collectively to sports in general, such as in the following (from [**the free dictionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sports)):

> Sports is a good way for children to get exercise.
>
> sports equipment

Comment: Just wondering why "Sports ARE good ways for children to get exercise" incorrect.

Comment: @JaveerBaker: The reason it sounds incorrect is that the "are" forces "sports" to refer to different sports, but semantically we didn't actually want to say that these individual activities themselves are "ways to get exercise", just like you would not say "Fruits are good ways to get vitamins.". Rather we want to say "engaging in sports is a good way to get exercise", and hence the singular "sports" can be used since it semantically refers to anything pertaining to sports, like in "sports day/field/equipment". It's not just a matter of referring to them as a group but as a whole.

Comment: @JaveerBaker Even if you use _sports_ in the plural here, there is no reason to make the [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement) plural as well. That just sounds strange. “Sports is/are _a good way_ for children to get exercise” are both perfectly fine. “Football and tennis are both _good ways_ for children to get exercise” works too, because those are seen as **different** ways of doing the same thing. In the same vein, “Meatballs are my favourite dish” (singular), but “Lasagne and meatballs are my favourite dishes” (because they’re different).

Comment: @JaveerBaker: Yes what *Janus* said as well, though I think "sports are a good way" uses metonymy to force the audience to take the plural "sports" to refer to "engaging in sports" since "a good way" is singular and grammatically does not match. Same for "fruits is a good way to get vitamins", which has to mean "eating fruits is a good way ...", while "fruits is a good way to attract flies" has to mean "having fruits around is a good way ...". In other words it is metonymy at work in his "sports are a good way ..." and "football and tennis are both good ways ...", not intrinsic semantics.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Do you agree with my analysis of your examples?

Comment: @user21820 Not the part about “a good way” not matching because it’s singular. The complement to an element does not necessarily have to be the same number as the element itself. “All the scattered chairs and tables were a difficult obstacle to manoeuvre around”, for example, employs no metonymy and has a plural subject with a singular complement. Viewing a set of subjects as a single, semantic unit does not have to be metonymy, and I don’t think it necessarily is with _sports_, though of course it **can** be.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yes I agree with your tables and chairs example, but it is different since one is taking them as a single group. In contrast I think the sports example isn't so simple since "way" just doesn't seem to go with sports. We can't for example say "One way to get exercise is tennis." without invoking metonymy but we can say "The main obstacle was all the scattered chairs and tables.".

Comment: @user21820 What’s wrong with “One way to get exercise is tennis”? It’s a perfectly cromulent sentence to me …

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: To me it is a clear example of metonymy. Perhaps my mental lexicon has a narrower range for "way" than you. =)

Answer (score -1):

Sports is definitely plural. You can have a singular sport (such as football or soccer), or multiple sports (such as football AND soccer).

Thus, the correct usage would be the ones you posed:

I like playing sports.
Sports have always been of interest to me.

Answer (score -2):

"Sports is good for you."

Here it is used collectively, meaning many sporting activities, so as a collective noun it is definitely singularly.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also indicated the correctness of the singular usage in a similar context.

Answer (score -4):

"Sports" when used with an s is taken as an adjective and is considered singluar. 
 For instance Learning sports is a good way to stay healthy.

In all other cases the word "sports" is plural.

Sports have taught me to be fit.