# Doubt about using plural form in this phrase "discuss about ...."

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Source: https://www.realmenrealstyle.com/public-restroom-rules/

I came across this article and thinking whether the use of plural form in the following sentence is necessary

> 2 . Conversation Etiquette 
>   ......
>
> This is not a time to be social and **discuss politics or sports**.

Why not just "discuss politic or sport"?
Why is it necessary to be plural?

Any help will/would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sports – singular or plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240840/sports-singular-or-plural); the plural form with singular agreement of 'politics' is doubtless covered elsewhere, but would be suitable on ELL.

Comment: Perhaps your native language is other than English. Some nouns in English are written with a final "s", but that does not indicate that they are a plural. These include words describing branches of knowledge such as "Mathematics, Physics, Economics, etc"...also diseases, such as "measles, mumps, etc.", as well as other newsworthy topics such as "sports" and "politics".

Answer (score 1):

*Politics* isn't really the plural of "politic" (which is an adjective). As a topic, "politics" is singular; as shorthand for "political considerations", it's plural, but again, one political consideration isn't "a politic", it's still "politics".

*Sports* is a little different. "Sport" is commonly used in British English, but not as common in American English. In both, "sports" is commonly plural. But it can still be used as a mass/uncountable noun.

[Here's a good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/244477/355372) for *sport*.

[Here's a good discussion](https://grammarist.com/usage/politics/) for *politics*.

Comment: Please do not make us wander off-site for sources and citations.