# Is it correct to say: English through sport or English through sports?

Tags: differences

This is the title of the workshop where students will participate in various activities related to sports (basketball, football, volleyball, running, jumping, etc.).

Comment: Are they somehow learning English by participating in these sports?

Comment: Yes...They will learn the basics and they will play handball, football, dodgeball...etc.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin et al.: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
discussion, debate, or giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the post,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: See *[Sports – singular or plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240840)*. Also of possible interest: *[“Sport” vs “Sports” Origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212851)*

Comment: @MetaEd - I was also given to understand that answers should not be simply bare assertions; since I could not provide any concrete backing for my assertion - it was best described as anecdotal from experience - I felt that proposing it as an answer was inappropriate under the guidelines.

Answer (score -2):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
SPORT -
(1): physical activity engaged in for pleasure
(2): a particular activity (such as an athletic game) so engaged in.
Since the title of the workshop refers to several activities there should be the plural form 'sports'.