# Why is "gymnastics" plural, "swimming" conjugated and "sport" singular? Is this even correct?

Tags: grammar

If this has been previously asked I'd be delighted to be pointed to that answer but despite searching I can't find an explanation.

I'm trying to construct some lexemes to describe sports.

It's bothering me no end that in official references (eg olympics: https://www.olympic.org/sports) they seem grammatically chaotic:

- sport

  - athletic**s**
  - badminton
  - gymnastic**s**
  - swim**ming**

Surely an "etymologically consistent" listing would look like:

- sport

  - athletic
  - badminton
  - gymnastic
  - swim

or alternatively

- sport

  - athleticking
  - badmintoning
  - gymnasticing
  - swimming

*(or something)*

If someone would be able to explain these inconsistencies it would provide a great deal of relief.

Comment: Sorry, but life is messy...;-)

Comment: Goodness gracious. 1 view. 1 downvote. No feedback. No explanation of what I've done wrong.

If anyone is ever curious to know what is wrong with SO, you have it right there. I'm sorry I evidentally don't understand how to use this particular SO.

Comment: Hey, I'm not your downvoter!  It's a fair question.  It's just that English has evolved using all kinds of source material and is often far from logical or predictable.

Comment: Isn't *gymnastics* singular half the time? Like *mathematics* and *physics*?

Comment: Part of this is answered by this question on [the etymology of -ics](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4656/191178).

Comment: I believe that the reason for the plural names is that those areas of sporting endeavour contain multiple disciplines (athletics, gymnastics) whereas some of the singular ones consist of variations on the same skill set and some of these have 'ing' endings (swimming, boxing) although some do not (archery is an example). The remaining ones are tournaments of a single named sport (badminton, tennis, beach volleyball)

Comment: Another part of this would be answered by the question in [sport vs sports](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/212851/191178) (if it had any good answers).

Comment: Swimming goes with knitting, dancing and reading.  Gymnastics goes with physics and economics.  Football goes with needlepoint and clarinet.  These differences occur in non-sporting contexts as well as sporting.

Comment: Uh, we're talking about ENGLISH here.  Consistency is a fiction.

Comment: Why would you think that words about sports, which have been developing since at least the 8th century BC, would be organized like a table of natural species?

Comment: One reason for the downvote(s): your question is not limited to one specific case such as asking why *gymnastics* and *athletics* appear to be plural. Instead, your question is rather broad, you would also like to know why some sports take the suffix -ing and while others the -s. Too many good questions cannot receive a full and satisfactory answer. I'll also add that I am surprised that no one so far has sought to support their answers with references and facts. Every response sounds like a personal opinion, however much it may be based on previous knowledge.

Comment: Gymnast and gymnastics are both nouns, neither is a verb. Judo is a noun, as is tennis, and football but the latter two can be used as verbs *tennising* and *footballing*. Where there is an action (verb) which necessitates a noun form; e.g. swim, drive, jump, run, the suffix –ing is added. It's called the gerund form.

Comment: Instead of swimming, try aquatics.  (I swear I'm typing this with a straight face.)

Comment: Athletics, gymnastics and aquatics group together several sporting activities, whilst swimming and badminton name a single sporting activity ...

Comment: Words develop and change based on many factors, most of which don't follow a formal structure. There is no one answer.

Comment: I would have thought that at Olympic level, the minton should be good.

Comment: @PeteKirkham - That's **bad**!

Answer (score 28):

You are looking at three different categories of activities:

- Groups, like gymnastics or athletics. Just as BoldBen said in their answer, those are actually a set of different activities (e.g. for athletics: vaulting, long jumping, high jumping, running, throwing, hurling and so on).
- Activities described by the act that is being performed, such as the ones listed in the previous example. Swimming and skiing are also on this category and so is curling, even if the etymology is not certain. Those are usually used for sports where a single athletic act (to bowl a ball = bowling) or activity (to swim = swimming) is required or where it really defines the sport.
- Proper names of sports, like pool, basketball, badminton, tennis, soccer, football, volleyball and so on. These can't be properly described with a single -ing word, because they are complex activities that are not defined by a single act (what do soccer player do? They run, they tackle, they kick, they block). As a consequence, we "play" those sports, we don't "do" them, so we can not say we're "badmintoning", we say we're "playing badminton" instead.

Comment: So basically: there are a few different families of naming conventions, and when there was a choice, different people at different times chose to apply one that stuck to any particular sporting event / activity.

Comment: I think your first bullet point is off the mark. -ics is a standalone suffix that can mean "study, knowledge, skill, practice" or "characteristic actions or activities" see www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ics ... there is no such thing as a "gymnastic" and indeed the word "gymnastics" is singular.

Comment: @ajd The terms "athletic pursuits" and "gymnastic exercises" are both plural. I believe that "athletics" is a short form of "athletic pursuits" (or activities) and gymnastics is short for "gymnastic exercises". The nouns were coined from the adjectives.

Answer (score 12):

I can explain some of the *-ing* forms. *Swimming, skiing, boxing, canoeing, fencing, diving, sailing, rowing, shooting, wrestling,* are things people might do (or might once have done in the past—who fences in their everyday life these days?) outside the context of sport. For these sports, the tendency seems to be use the *-ing* form for the name of the sport as well.

This doesn't explain *curling*, but there are exceptions to every rule.

Comment: It does explain curling, see: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curl#Verb

Answer (score 8):

I originally posted this as a comment because it is an opinion and I couldn't think of any way back it up. As there have been other answers without supporting references I thought I would add this as an answer.

I believe that the reason for the plural names is that those areas of sporting endeavour contain multiple disciplines (athletics, gymnastics) where the different events require different skill sets. In the case of athletics most runners do not jump or throw things, most jumpers do not throw or run (except to gain momentum for their jumps) and most throwers do not jump or run except to gain momentum for their throws. The exceptions are the tri-, pent-, hept- and decathletes.

At the other extreme there are people who compete in named sports where there is a knockout or league competition but they are competing multiple times in a single named sport (badminton, tennis and beach volleyball for example)

In between there is a class of sports with many different competitions which all require excellence in the same skill (examples are swimming, boxing, cycling and fencing)

There are still a few sports where the name does not fit this pattern (for instance horse riding which could qualify for an 'ics' ending by its diversity), archery (which would have to have an 'ing' ending if it were to fit the pattern) and Karate and Tae Kwon Do (which would have an 'ing' ending if the categorisation were strictly enforced) but the names of these sports are historic. As Dan said in a comment above "life is messy".

Answer (score 6):

The choice of which form to use often comes down to what sounds ‘nice’ while not sounding confusing. I expect that the etymology of each term will depend somewhat on which words were already considered to be established when the sport was named.

For example, *athletic* sounds like an adjective, while *athletics* doesn’t. If you started with *athlete* and wanted to know what kind of carnival they might participate in, you might try to call it an *athletic* carnival. But to keep it from being contrasted with a *boring* carnival or a *sedentary* one purely by substituting a word that looks like it is of the same part of speech, you might use the plural *athletics*.

Likewise with gymnastics.

*Archery* doesn’t have this problem, so the ‘singular’ form works. *Swimming* is a counterexample, but I suspect the more common / older sporting names are derived from verb usage: “I am going *to swim” - “I am going swimming” - “We are having a swimming competition”.

Comment: This is a great answer. Sometimes people look for logical or formal reasons for things whereas aesthetics and convenience are just as likely to play a role.

Comment: Yes, I think much of this usage is arbitrary, likely set at some time by some influential speaker (or editor, or writer) and followed out of custom. "Sport", singular, is UK usage; in the US and Canada papers have "Sports" pages and TV has "Sports" categories. But UK students study "Maths",  where North Americans study "Math".

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer as such, but it would appear the "ing" endings are Old or Middle English, the "ie"/"y" endings are Old French, while the "ic" endings are Latin (presumably from the Greek).

Answer (score 1):

"Gymnastics" and "athletics" when referring to the sports are not plural. One says that gymnastics is a sport, not that gymnastics are a sport. I believe that these words have the [-ics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ics) suffix which denotes a skill or practice (like "linguistics" or "physics").